# Why this for loop of array uses newARRAY.length-1?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop, arraylist

Hello I'm beginner at java now I've arrived to arrays here is a for loop to sort number from highest to lowest, my question is why the instructor used

> newARRAY.length-1

?

```
public static int [] integers;

public static int [] sortArray(int[] array){
    boolean PeaceArray = true;
    int temp;
    int [] newARRAY = Arrays.copyOf(array,array.length);
    while(PeaceArray){
        PeaceArray = false;
        for(int i=0;i<newARRAY.length-1;i++){
            if(newARRAY[i]< newARRAY[i+1]){
                temp = newARRAY[i];
                newARRAY[i] = newARRAY[i+1];
                newARRAY[i+1] = temp;
                PeaceArray = true;

            }


        }


    }

    return newARRAY;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried substituting all values of `i` in `newARRAY[i+1]`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't understand you

Comment: @Abdelillah try changing `newARRAY.length-1` to something else, see what happens when you run it.

Comment: When `i` is at the last index, `i+1` will be out of bounds.

Comment: What other value did you expect your instructor to use, and why did you expect that? If you answer `newARRAY.length`, without the `-1`, then what do you think happens for a highest value of `i` when you do `newARRAY[i+1]`, and why do you think that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array start the index with 0

ex:
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
then a.length=5 but a[5] does't exits in the array

a[0]=1

a[1]=2

a[2]=3

a[3]=4

a[4]=5

for this reason we use a.length-1 instead of a.length

Answer (score 1):

> Normally the first index of a java array starts from zero (0), but the length property of
>   the arrays gives an actual count of the array.

For example, consider the following integer array:

```
int[] numbers = {40, 55, 63, 17, 22, 68, 89, 97, 89}
```

This array can be represented graphically as well like below[image: array description]

So if we are to run a loop for this array like:

```
for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
   //this loop runs 9 times
}
```

I the above loop `i` was initialized to `0` and the maximum value `i` can get to is `8` but the loop will run 9 times because if you count all the way from `0` to `8` you get `9`

But if you run a loop like this

```
for(int i=0; i<numbers.length-1; i++){
   //this loop runs 8 times
}
```

The loop will run 8 times but the maximum value `i` can get to is `7`

Your instructor used `newARRAY.length-1` because he didn't want the maximum value of `i` to exceed `the immediate lower number following newARRAY.length-1` because he was using the value of `i+1` to index the array `newArray` somewhere in the code.

If he hadn't used `newARRAY.length-1` in the code, when `i` gets to its maximum value, `newARRAY[i+1]` would give an `IndexOutOfbounds` error, because the last index of `newARRAY` would have been exceeded because of the `1` he is adding to `i` to access the `newARRAY`

I hope you understood this.